# Padding with Leading zeros for Pandas data frame column with data as numpy array

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame df,I used following code to create the data frame

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
data = np.array([11234466, 77777777, 12345678, 23452345])
data1 = np.array([99999999, 66666666, 44332211, 56781234])
df=pd.DataFrame({'A' : [data.tolist()]})
df1=pd.DataFrame({'A' : [data1.tolist()]})
df=pd.concat([df,df1])
```

whose one column, Column A contains numpy array. with data type as object.The column A looks like

```
           A
 [11234466, 77777777, 12345678, 23452345]
 [99999999, 66666666, 44332211, 56781234]
```

All the values are integer and mostly 8 digits number. I want to make it 10 digits string with leading zeros. Like this one

```
      A
['0011234466', '0077777777', '0012345678', '0023452345']
['0099999999', '0066666666', '0044332211', '0056781234']
```

I thought to try below code

```
 df['A'] = df['A'].astype(str)
 df['A'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x: x.zfill(10))
```

However, this doesn't pad zeros but leave the column as it is. Can you suggest me how should I pad column A's value with leading zeros?

---

Using Jazrel's suggestion, I'm getting this output

```
       A
0  [000000000[, 0000000001, 0000000001, 000000000...
0  [000000000[, 0000000009, 0000000009, 000000000... `
```

Comment: Please could you give an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). What you describe works for me; there's something else going on that you're not showing us.

Comment: @MarkDickinson,Yes, My error message disappeared after restarting spyder. But it's not filling the value with leading zeros.

Comment: @MarkDickinson, also I have added the code, I used to create the data frame. This is my test code which I created to use before applying the logic in future.I don't have anything other than this

Comment: Don't use numpy arrays or lists inside a DataFrame. It makes a trivial task harder for no good reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use `list comprehension`:

```
df['A'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x: [str(y).zfill(10) for y in x])
print (df)
                                                  A
0  [0011234466, 0077777777, 0012345678, 0023452345]
0  [0099999999, 0066666666, 0044332211, 0056781234]
```

---

```
df['A'] = [[str(y).zfill(10) for y in x] for x in df['A']]
print (df)
                                                  A
0  [0011234466, 0077777777, 0012345678, 0023452345]
0  [0099999999, 0066666666, 0044332211, 0056781234]
```

Similar solution with `format`:

```
df['A'] = [['{:010d}'.format(y) for y in x] for x in df['A']]
print (df)
                                                  A
0  [0011234466, 0077777777, 0012345678, 0023452345]
0  [0099999999, 0066666666, 0044332211, 0056781234]
```

EDIT:

```
data = np.array([[11234466], [77777777], [12345678], [23452345]])
data1 = np.array([[99999999], [66666666], [44332211], [56781234]])
df=pd.DataFrame({'A' : [data.tolist()]})
df1=pd.DataFrame({'A' : [data1.tolist()]})
df=pd.concat([df,df1])

df['A'] = [[['{:010d}'.format(z) for z in y] for y in x] for x in df['A']]
print (df)
                                                   A
0  [[0011234466], [0077777777], [0012345678], [00...
0  [[0099999999], [0066666666], [0044332211], [00...
```

Comment: But using this code I'm getting different output.Added in my original post. Can you please check?

Comment: No data. This is test code for my future work.I used your first approach.I will try other approach too. Currently I have only this code

Comment: I got it, need remove `df['A'] = df['A'].astype(str)`

Comment: Do you remove `df['A'] = df['A'].astype(str)` and same problem?

Comment: I converted it to pandas.core.series.Series also using `x.astype(int)` but got error message `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`

Comment: Yes, because nested values. But if it working with samples and with real data not, then it is problem in data :(

Comment: yes I removed df['A'] = df['A'].astype(str) & then also same problem

Comment: Then can you please suggest same for  pandas.core.series.Series

Comment: If series is `s` then change only `df['A']` to `s`

Comment: Hmmm, I got idea. Can you send me to my email sample data in dict? `print (df.to_dict())` ?